# create multi-dimensional container/array from java bean objects

Tags: java

I am trying to create a multi-dimensional array from the java bean objects. I am getting a response as:

```
"data":[
     {product, elementType, element, ruleId, isActive, description}, 
     {product, elementType, element, ruleId, isActive, description}
        ]
```

But, I want response as:

```
        “data”:[
         {“product”:”this will be a product”,”elementTypes”:[
        {“elementType”:”this will be an element type,”elements”:
      [
           {
             “element”:”this is an element name”,
             “ruleId”:”this is the rule Id”,
            “isActive”:” Is the rule active (Y or N)”,
            “description”:”description of rule”
           },
           {              
             “element”:”this is another element name”,
             “ruleId”:”this is the rule Id”,
            “isActive”:” Is the rule active (Y or N)”,
             “description”:”description of rule”
            },
         ]
         },  
         {“elementType”:”this will be another element            
          type”,”elements”:
        [
           {              
             “element”:”this is a element name”,
             “ruleId”:”this is the rule Id”,
            “isActive”:” Is the rule active (Y or N)”,
            “description”:”description of rule”

           },
           {              
             “element”:”this is another element name”,
             “ruleId”:”this is the rule Id”,
            “isActive”:” Is the rule active (Y or N)”,
              “description”:”description of rule”
           },
         ]
        }
       ]},  
        {“product”:”this will be another product”,”elementTypes”:[
        {“elementType”:”this will be an element type,”elements”:
        [
           {              
             “element”:”this is another element name”,
             “ruleId”:”this is the rule Id”,
            “isActive”:” Is the rule active (Y or N)”,
            “description”:”description of rule”
            }
            ]
            }]
            }
          }
```

I am not sure how to get common elements.
Can anyone please suggest me how to get this format in java?